# Java Persisence - Tables are created, but not the data

Tags: java, persistence, glassfish-4, java-ee-5

My connection pool pinged successfully
Tables are created. Data that I wanted to insert into that table not inserted. Any guess..any help!

Here is my code
`
    
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        
            jdbc/supun
            false

`

Comment: Where do you expect the data to come from?

Comment: when a database and a programmer love each other very much the stork comes and fills the database with data

Comment: Without seeing your code that actually tries to store the data, I can only guess... Is there anything at all in the logs? Could it be that you're not committing the transaction ever?

Comment: Where is the data ? Your code doesn't show anything relevant to data import.

Comment: Thanks guys... Finally I solved it.. Sorry for late reply